# Pausable ERC20 Tokens too much centralisation?

Tags: erc-20, ico

I see that a lot of ERC20 tokens are pausable. One example is MANA:
https://etherscan.io/token/decentraland#readContract

Doesn't this put a very high level of centralisation on the token? Potentially one person has the power to pause MANA indefinitely - a token with tens of millions invested in it could just be shut off.

I understand the benefit of Pausable. If there's a hack everything can be paused, but are we at a stage now where the ERC20 standard token doesn't require Pausable anymore allowing it to be fully decentralised?

Answer (score 2):

It's a choice of the developers. Keep in mind that **it's not because it's on the blockchain/relies on it that it should be trustless**!

It's up to the individuals acquiring any token to know what they are up to.

In the end, it's up to the developers of the token to make that choice, accordingly to the use of the token and the DApp.

Comment: I understand it's much choice as a developer. I can decide to inherit from pausable or not